# KiCad pin reordering from PCB designer to avoid crossings

Tags: kicad, pinout

Sometimes pins of a part are equivalent in the sense it does not really matter which is used (typical examples being connectors, terminals, GPIOs.)

Is there a way in KiCad to reorder the pins in the PCB designer PcbNew so that crossings are avoided and feed those changes back to the electrical schematic?

Comment: For function specific questions the dedicated Kicad-forum is a better source for answers (https://forum.kicad.info/). The developers and experienced users frequently improve certain parts of the software based on user input.

Comment: In which way do you want to "reorder" pins in pcb new? I mean, the pin numbering is given by the footprint, so you must not change it. On the other side you can create new component symbols where you can arrange pin arbitrarily. So in my understanding you would usually go the other way around...

Comment: @SimSon Sometimes multiple pins of a part (say processor with GPIO pins or connector) can have same/interchangeable functionality and from perspective of pcb layout it might be preferrable to have specific pins of one part connected to specific of other part where in shematics it does not matter. So position of pin 1 is given by footprint, but maybe you can also use pin 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WireIt plugin (https://github.com/xesscorp/WireIt) is the best option if you are using 5.1.x

There is discussion of incorporating such a function but I believe this is a v7 EPIC